# What is the 'OnDockChanged' event handler?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I'm trying to design a button that has the DockChanged EH that knows the height & width of its paren't container (panel) and adjusts its metrics accordingly. E.g. button has text and icon, but if button width is in a panel that is too small, it will just show its icon and disable the text, etc.

Here's the method i'm trying to invoke the method with:

`InnerPanel.DockChanged += HandleDockChanged;`

Here's the method i'm trying to invoke the method on:

```
private void HandleDockChanged(EventArgs args)
        {
            //sorry for magic numbers
            if (Parent.Height < Height || Parent.Width < Width)
            {
                TextLabel.Enabled = false;
                InnerPanel.Width = ButtonWidth;
                InnerPanel.Height = ButtonHeight;

                Padding = new Padding(1);
            }else
            {
                TextLabel.Enabled = true;
                InnerPanel.Width = ButtonWidth * 2;
                InnerPanel.Height = ButtonWidth * 2;
            }
        }
```

Comment: IMO, it's not clear what you're asking here. Are you changing the Dock Property value at some point? Or did you mean to override `OnResize` instead? -- In the question's title, you have `OnDockChanged`, which is related to the inherited Control (a derived Button Type? Or just deriving from Control?), in code, you're subscribing to the `DockChanged` event of an undefined Control. Try to provide a better description of the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thank you, i need more experience with C# to know what i'm talking about, i'll rectify any misinfomration I have